# Untrusted publisher for Powershell profile modules after creating, installing, and signing with certificate?

Tags: powershell, self-signed-certificate

I'm still getting untrusted publisher after creating a self-signed certificate and installing it on a system, when trying to run my Powershell Profile sub modules?

```
Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File \\someserver.somedomain.org\Redirected\xxxxxx\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\dasIncludedModule.psm1 is published by
CN=PowerShell User and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"): R
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Help about_Signing` (also [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847874.aspx)) to learn about self signing scripts.  Sounds like you missed the step to import your public key into the certificate store on the local PC.

Comment: No; I did that.  Into Trusted Certificates just like Scott Hanselman said in his tutorial.